# How to disable system beep for non-privileged user

Tags: linux, audio

How to disable system beep on Linux? I don't have superuser powers so I cannot recompile kernel/unload module.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For beeps generated in your shell (which seem to be the most annoying ones), add this to "**~/.inputrc**":

```
set bell-style none
```

Note that this is not terminal- but host-specific. That means that when you log in to another computer via **`ssh`** where this isn't set, the beep is back. (I tested on Fedora)

Comment: That's not going to help; all it does is tell certain applications (such as the shell) that *you* do not want them to beep. It won't effect other users, and it wouldn't really do anything in the case of non-local logins anyway: their terminal bell is on **their** terminal, not the console.

Comment: Please read the question and my answer: He isn't root and wants to do it for his user account and that it only helps in the local shell is explicitly stated in my answer.

Comment: **Mind the gap**: existing ~/.inputrc *overrides* /etc/inputrc, which can have defined some interesting things.  For example on Debian this can break Ctrl+Left/Right for words and/or some Rxvt-specific bindings--See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108098/9365).

Answer (score 2):

There's various levels at which beeps can be controlled by the user. Here's some I'm aware of:

**APPLICATION LEVEL**

- `export LESS="$LESS"' -q'` - adds -q to the default options for `less` so it doesn't ring the bell (eg. when trying to scroll past the end of a file)
- `echo 'set bell-style none' >> ~/.inputrc` - disables bell for all applications using `readline` (restart your terminal to see effect)

**TERMINAL LEVEL**

- `xterm -vb` - enables "visual bell", which flashes the terminal window instead of making an audible noise. You can add `xterm*visualBell: true` to your X resources (`~/.Xdefaults`) to change the default. Most terminal emulators include a similar option.

**X SERVER LEVEL**

- `xset b off` - disables X server bell

**MACHINE LEVEL?**

- `alsamixer` - mute or turn down the `Speaker` and `Bell` channels

In my case muting the ALSA channels didn't help - I still got a bell sometimes from the builtin speaker (even with headphones plugged in). But disabling the X server bell got rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already unchecked "Enable system beep" in System -> Preferences -> Sound -> System Beep?

Comment: This assumes some desktop environment? GNOME?