# stop ding notification in ubuntu - windows 10 app

Tags: ubuntu, audio, notifications, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu Windows 10 app, but when ever I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or miss spell anything ding notification sound is coming, I am trying to find an option to stop it.

Comment: Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415497/117549

Comment: This is probably a property of the terminal app, what options does it have? Has it got any menus. Also Note LSW is Gnu/Linux without Linux: it is some of the user mode programs, it is nowhere near as good as the real thing.

Comment: This is a Windows specific, so may be off-topic here . See [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-off-windows-explorer-click-sounds-in-windows-vista/).